# Scipy: Speed up kernel density estimation's score_sample method?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to get the observed probability density using kernel density estimation. This is how I use the kde:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
kde = KernelDensity().fit(sample)
```

The problem is that, when I try to get the probability densitity of every point

```
kde_result = kde.score_samples(sample)
```

The speed is very slow. How can I speed it up?

The sample is consist of `300,000 (x,y)` points.

Comment: why would you want to get the density at every point?

Comment: You may try to initialize `KernelDensity()` with non-default values for `atol` and/or `rtol`.

Comment: @cel, I'm using a method to create a `predict model`, it need to calculate the `mean square error` of a `probabiltiy density function`. So I use `kde` to estimate the `observed pdf`, and then do the `(predict - observed)**2`

Comment: @Chris, the `init` (to create the `kde`) speed is OK. The troubling thing is the `score_sample` method when querying a big dataset.

Comment: So your predict model outputs a pdf as well? I am having problems understanding `calculate the mean square error of a probability density function` - mathematically this sounds somehow wrong.

Comment: @cel, yes, the predict model outpus a pdf as well. And I think that's wrong too, but I need to try it first. Its essence is that you need to `create a predict pdf`, and how do do that? By `minimizing the mean square error` of the predict and the oberserved pdf, and that's `(predict - observed)**2`. And that's why I need the observed pdf, i.e. `kde`.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case somebody is searching for an answert to this question, it is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625094/scipy-parallel-computing-in-ipython-notebook). There it is described that you can easily speed up execution by parallelizing the computation with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

This bit of code will do the job (also from the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625094/scipy-parallel-computing-in-ipython-notebook)):

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

def parrallel_score_samples(kde, samples, thread_count=int(0.875 * multiprocessing.cpu_count())):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(thread_count) as p:
        return np.concatenate(p.map(kde.score_samples, np.array_split(samples, thread_count)))

kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=2.0,atol=0.0005,rtol=0.01).fit(sample) 
kde_result = parrallel_score_samples(kde, sample)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30872663)

Comment: I just edited the answer