# Scipy: parallel computing in ipython notebook?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I'm doing a `kernel density estimation` of a dataset (a collection of points).

The `estimation process` is ok, the problem is that, when I'm trying to get the `density value` for each point, the speed is very slow:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
# this speed is ok
kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=2.0,atol=0.0005,rtol=0.01).fit(sample) 
# this is very slow
kde_result = kde.score_samples(sample)
```

The sample is consist of `300,000 (x,y) points`.

I'm wondering if it's possible to make it run parallely, so the speed would be quicker?

For example, maybe I can divide the `sample` in to smaller sets and run the `score_samples` for each set at the same time? Specifically:

1. I'm not familliar with `parallel computing` at all. So I'm wondering if it's applicable in my case?
2. If this can really speed up the process, what should I do? I'm just running the script in `ipython notebook`, and have no prior expereince in this, is there any good and simple example for my case?

I'm reading http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/parallel_intro.html now.

UPDATE:

```
import cProfile
cProfile.run('kde.score_samples(sample)')

        64 function calls in 8.653 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    8.653    8.653 <string>:1(<module>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _methods.py:31(_sum)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 base.py:870(isspmatrix)
        1    0.000    0.000    8.653    8.653 kde.py:133(score_samples)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 numeric.py:464(asanyarray)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 shape_base.py:60(atleast_2d)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 validation.py:105(_num_samples)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 validation.py:126(_shape_repr)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 validation.py:153(<genexpr>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 validation.py:268(check_array)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 validation.py:43(_assert_all_finite)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {hasattr}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
        1    8.652    8.652    8.652    8.652 {method 'kernel_density' of 'sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'sum' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a different kernel? With so many points, the choice of kernel should have only a marginal effect, but 'linear' and 'tophat' maybe faster to calculate.

Comment: @Rob, just tried `linear`, still very slow on `kde_result = kde.score_samples(sample)`

Comment: You stated that you want parallelism to make it quicker. This is not necessarily true. First, [profile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-profile) your code to check the hotspots. Once you're sure what should be optimized, see what you _can_ do to optimize it. We both have a gut feeling on what is taking long, but profiling will give you a much better insight (something explicit you can look up and maybe someone else already tried an optimization)

Comment: @FelipeLema this is really what I should looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: @FelipeLema, could you see my update?

Comment: Unfortunatelly the hard work is being done [cython](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2d559ba20a7102aee140ef7d2f49bf279b347b06/sklearn/neighbors/kd_tree.pyx) at `kernel_density`. I'm not aware of a parallel implementation of this, so it looks you're going to have to start from scratch. I found [this post](http://spartanideas.msu.edu/2014/06/20/an-introduction-to-parallel-programming-using-pythons-multiprocessing-module/#Kernel-density-estimation-as-benchmarking-function) that might help you get started and edited the question so a dev from scikit can give you a better insight.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of parallelization using [multiprocessing built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process) :

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

def parrallel_score_samples(kde, samples, thread_count=int(0.875 * multiprocessing.cpu_count())):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(thread_count) as p:
        return np.concatenate(p.map(kde.score_samples, np.array_split(samples, thread_count)))

kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=2.0,atol=0.0005,rtol=0.01).fit(sample) 
kde_result = parrallel_score_samples(kde, sample)
```

As you can see from code above, `multiprocessing.Pool` allows you to map a pool of worker processes executing `kde.score_samples` on a subset of your samples.
The speedup will be significant if your processor have enough cores.