# Generate array / matrix of kernel density over all extension

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, kernel-density

I'd like extracting all values of a kernel density function to a matrix (a numpy array with shape ymax,xmax). It is very easy to plot the kernel density with seaborn:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import stats, random


x = random.sample(range(2000, 4500), 1000)
y = random.sample(range(0, 2500), 1000)

sns.kdeplot(x,y)
```

[image: all_kernel]

And it's also quite easy to extract density values at specified positions:

```
values = np.array(list(zip(x, y)))
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values.T)

# Extracting kernel value at [xcoords],[ycoords] 
kernel([[2500,3700,4500],[500,2000,2500]])
```

> array([3.09998436e-07, 4.63280866e-07, 1.56687705e-09])

The question is, how do I extract all possible values into a matrix (given an extension)? I want to do matrix calculations with that. If I try to use the previous method and give it the coordinates of every pixel, it's just slow.

```
#Fast      (extracting kernel density value at every 100 xy points)
kernel(np.array(list(
           itertools.product(
                range(0,1000,100),
                range(0,1000,100))
           )).T)

# Slow     (extracting kernel density value at all possible xy points)
kernel(np.array(list(
           itertools.product(
                 range(0,1000),
                 range(0,1000))
           )).T)
```

Comment: I could be totally off here, but it doesn't look like you're tackling this the right way. [Check it out](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is slow because `itertools.product` is a *iterable that produces millions of pure-Python objects* (integers and tuple) that needs to be decoded and translated to native integers by Numpy. You can use Numpy directly to efficiently generate such array:

```py
rng = np.arange(1000)
x = np.repeat(rng, 1000)
y = np.tile(rng, 1000)
idx = np.hstack((x[:, None], y[:, None]))
kernel(idx)
```

The generation of the indices is 80 times faster on my machine.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! Is there any reason to use np.hstack? I need to transpose idx in order for kernel to not give error, and that's equivalent to a np.array(x,y). So I skipped the whole idx creation. Happy new year!

Comment: Thank you. `np.array(x,y)` does not appear to work. Did you mean `np.array((x,y))`? Generally, I tend not to use `np.array` except for input lists since AFAIK it have a significantly higher overhead for small arrays. I also find functions like `concatenate`, `hstack` and `vstack` more readable. I think there is no problem to use `np.array` besides this. Feel free use the one you prefer ;) .

Comment: Thanks, good to learn! Yes, I meant np.array([x,y]). As a final note, even though your solution is much faster, it still takes a prohibitive long time for the 20 000 by 20 000 matrices I want to use. I also tried sklearn's KernelDensity and I see others have the same problem and partial solutions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607552/scipy-speed-up-kernel-density-estimations-score-sample-method

Comment: This is a quite big matrix. IDK if such kernel-density functions are efficiently implemented or if it is fundamentally expensive to compute. If the function release the GIL, then you could try to use a multithreaded implementation. Otherwise, you could try to desperately use a parallel multiprocessing implementation. Alternatively, you could implement your own kernel function using Numba but this is probably not easy. Another solution is to find a fast C/C++ library implementing that and write a Cython wrapping code.

Comment: A simple solution is also to open an issue on https://github.com/scipy/scipy to ask developer to optimize the code (assuming it could) since the speed of such function appear to be important for many people.